# Python-Multiprocessing Error when working with astropy

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, astropy, fits

I want to speed up some scripts that I need to analyze astronomical data. I have scripts that are run independently for every single image file that I have (which are in .fits file format). I was trying to simply start multiple files at once using `Multiprocessing.Pool()` and map. My code looks like this:

```
def sextract(name):
    # creates a class instance and calls the method
    astro = astrometry(name, *some_more_args)
    astro.sextract()

arguments = ['PART1_cal.fits', 'PART2_cal.fits', 'PART3_cal.fits',
            'PART4_cal.fits', 'PART5_cal.fits']

with closing(Pool()) as pool:
    pool.map(sextract, arguments)
    pool.terminate()
```

and the astrometry.sextract method looks like this:

```
def sextract(self):
    sex = 'sextractor'
    headerlist = ['JD-START', 'OBSERVER', 'DATE', 'TM-START', 'OBJECT',
                  'FLTRNAME', 'RA', 'DEC', 'AIRMASS',
                  'EXP_TIME']
    calib = self._from
    # calls the SourceExtrator in the shell with a config-file and
    # the file name
    os.system(sex + ' -c ' + self.sexpath + ' ' + calib)
    # copies the extracted file to a folder on an external HDD
    shutil.copy2(self.ext_path, self._to + '/' +
                 calib.split('/')[-1])
    # opens the old .fits image and extracts the header
    old = fits.open(calib)
    o = old[0].header
    # opens the new(copied) .fits image and extracts the header
    # this produces the error
    extr = fits.open(self._to + '/' + calib.split('/')[-1],
                     mode='update')                         
    e = extr[1].header
    # goes through the old header entries and copies all entries 
    # in the to the new header
    for g in headerlist:
        e[g] = o[g]
    # saves the new header to the new(copied) file and closes both 
    # files
    extr[1].header = e
    extr.flush()
    extr.close()
    old.close()
```

Every time I run this code, I get an `IOError: Header missing END card.`, which is thrown by the line where I open the new .fits and put it in the variable `extr`. At first I thought this would happen because the copy procedure would take too long, and the python tries to access the file before it's finished copying. I inserted a `time.sleep(10)` to check that, but the error still appears.

I tried using `pool.apply()` and the normal `map()` and in both cases I don't get an error. When using `pool.apply()` it takes almost as long as for the `map()` case though, so I haven't really accomplished anything doing it this way.

I know this is a very specific question, but I hope someone might know where my problem lies, or got something similar working already.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do (inline-code comments)? Also it would be helpful if you could check that your code really looks like this. It seems there are some missing/wrong indentations.

Comment: you were right, there was a wrong indentation. Sorry for the mistake. I also added some explanations of what the code is supposed to do

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you just create a file using `os.system` (sextractor) and then copy that result file and when you try to open the original result again it gives you an Exception?

Comment: yes, the source extractor creates a new file, which is then copied to some other place. But I get the error when I try to access the newly created and moved file. I believe the Header missing END card means, that something is not correct with the file it tries to access. If I look at the moved file, I can see that there is an END card, so I'm kind of confused as to why this error is thrown

Comment: Use the subprocess module instead of os.system(). apply() and map() do totally different things. Since most of the work you're doing is in the sextractor call there's not much advantage to using multiprocessing like that. Also are you sure the files you're producing are valid in the first place (multiprocessing aside)?

Comment: You appear to copy `self.ext_path` (instead of `calib`), and it's anyone's guess whether that is actually a FITS file. And what kind of catalog file are you creating with SExtractor; what is e.g., CATALOG_TYPE in the SExtractor parameter list? There is too little information to go on in your question.

Comment: NB, from a Python point of view: don't use attributes/variable names like `__to__` and `__from__`: generally, such attribute names (double underscores, both before and after), are reserved for special methods. Just name them `_to` and `_from` if you like them to be private attributes. Also, consider using utilities such as `os.path.join` and `os.path.dirname`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm not a very versed programmer, that's why probably a lot choices I've made are not the smartest. The code that I have written is working though. All the files that are created are working and are valid. I have used this code for almost a year now, I just wanted to speed up the process of working with many files.

@Evert I'm copying the `self.ext_path` file, which is some test.fits in a directory which doesn't change.